# Logging for asynchronous process in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a set of commands that needs to be run parallel. each of the commands takes atleast 30 mins to execute
I am currently using

```
start abc.exe
start 123.exe
start xyz.exe
```

I want them to log the outputs while it is running. For this purpose, I am using `wintee`. 
Wintee allows the program to run in the foreground and log them in background.

But the combination of start and wintee is not working as expected. 
I am seeing the command lines executed one by one and wintee creates the blank log file instantly.

My current code:

```
start abc.exe | wintee .Logs\log1.txt
start 123.exe | wintee .Logs\log2.txt
start xyz.exe | wintee .Logs\log3.txt
```

Any help/alternate will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
start "" cmd /c "abc.exe | wintee .Logs\log1.txt"
start "" cmd /c "123.exe | wintee .Logs\log2.txt"
start "" cmd /c "xyz.exe | wintee .Logs\log3.txt"
```

The pipe needs to be managed by `cmd.exe`. In your code the pipe in defined between the `start` command and `wintee` and is managed by the same instance that runs the batch file. Just spawn a new instance for each of the processes

Comment: It not even spawned a new process. It just printed the cmds in the window.